# An inequality about Lipschitz mapping and measurable sets in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> Let $\mathbb{R^n}$ be n-dimensional Euclidean space and mapping $f: \mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ be Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $c>0$. Then there is a constant $\epsilon$ that depends solely on $c$ and $n$ such that for any bounded interval $I$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$, $\mu^{*}(f(I))\leq \epsilon \cdot Vol(I)$ where the $\mu^{*}$ is Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Let $I=I_{1}\times I_{2}\times... \times I_{n}$ in which $I_{k}=[a_{k},b_{k}]$ for $1\leq k\leq n$. I found the center of $I$, that is, $x_{0}=(\frac {a_{1}+b_{1}}{2},...,\frac {a_{n}+b_{n}}{2})$. For each $y=f(x)\in f(I)$, $||y-f(x_{0})||\leq c||x-x_{0}||\leq c \sqrt{\sum_{1}^{n}(\frac {a_{k}+b_{k}}{2})^{2}}$. Let $K= \frac c2 \sqrt{\sum_{1}^{n}(a_{k}+b_{k})^{2}}$. Then $f(I)$ is contained in a bounded interval $I^{'}=\prod_{1}^{n}[c_{k}-K,c_{k}+K]$ with center $f(x_{0})=(c_{1},c_{2},...,c_{n})$. But there is a gap to prove the volume of $I^{'}$ is less than $\epsilon \cdot Vol(I)=\epsilon \prod_{1}^{n}(b_{k}-a_{k})$. I guess I need some inequalities here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should post the details of your construction of I'. We can say much more than that this product of intervals is bounded, we can put bounds on these intervals in terms of the Lipschitz constant and the size of the original intervals.

Comment: I add some details. Thanks.

Comment: This problem is from Royden's Real Analysis (Page 436, Ex 24)..I didn't find any hint.

Comment: So the issue with this approach is that if V is a very thin rectangle (some dimensions are small some are large), then your estimate on \|x-x_0\| is not so good because ``typical" points in your rectangle are far closer to the centre than your worst-case estimate.

Instead, you can first prove the corresponding estimate for balls, and then try to use this together with the definition of the Lebesgue outer measure to complete your proof.

Comment: Yeah, the key of this problem is to find a thin rectangle. I am considering a better estimate.. Can you give me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lipschitz condition implies that balls of radius $r$ map into balls of radius $cr$ under $f$.

This implies that $\mu^*(f(B))\leq c^n\mu^*(B)$ for balls $B$.

Now by the definition of the Lebesgue outer measure, we can find a countable sequence of balls $B_j$ such that $V\subseteq \cup_j B_j$ and $\sum_j\mu^*(B_j)<\mu^*(V)+\epsilon$.

So 
$$\mu^*(f(V))\leq \mu^*(\cup_j f(B_j))\leq \sum_j \mu^*(f(B_j))$$

$$\leq c^n\sum_j \mu^*(B_j) <c^n(\mu^*(V)+\epsilon) $$

As $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we obtain $\mu^*(f(V))\leq c^n \mu^*(V)$ and this completes the proof.